# how to make bash script password protected?

Tags: bash

The program shall ask the secret key to run the program; a user should program this secret key in advance. If the user enters the correct secret key it should move to the next step(i.e. the script should execute), else it should prompt to enter the correct key four times and then exit the program.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not very clean but this will work:

```
PASS="foo"
n=0
until [ "$n" -ge 4 ]
do
    read -p "Enter password: "
    if [[ $REPLY == $PASS ]]
    then
        break
    else
        echo "Wrong password, try again"
        n=$((n+1))
     fi
done
if [ $n == 4 ]
then
    echo "Timed out from too many attempts!"
    exit 0
fi
### CONTINUE SCRIPT HERE ###
```